# Spring JPA: Saving An entity having association with an entity which is sort of master table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mapping, persist

I have following entities and their relationship in database tables.

Entity **TransactionType** which will contain a master set of data which will never change/or rarely will get changed.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ONB_TRANS_TYPE")
@Cacheable(true)
public class TransactionType implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6630648311619744810L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer ID;

    @Column(name = "TRANS_TYPE_NAME",unique=true)
    private String transTypeName;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Another Enitity **CandidateTransaction** which has a foreign key from TransactionType, in table the relationship between the two tables is the normal Pk-FK relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ONB_CANDIDATE_TRANS")
public class CandidateTransaction implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3615632069112078119L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer ID;

    //FK to ONB_Candidate_Info table
    @Column(name="CANDIDATE_ID")
    private String candidateId;

    private UUID TRANS_IDENTIFIER;


    @OneToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name="TRANS_TYPE_ID")
    private TransactionTypeDTO transactionType;
}
```

I have made a Unidirectional OneToOneMapping between two entities.
Now when I want to persist an object of CandidateTransaction, I am doing following while saving and it throws me an error stating you cannot insert null in TRANS_TYPE_ID.
What I want to ask is do I have to explicitly fetch the Trans_TYPE_ID from Master Table (ONB_TRANS_TYPE) or I shouldn't ORM do this ?? As I have given the mapping ??

```
@Service
public class CandidateTransactionManagerImpl implements CandidateTransactionManager {

    @Autowired
    private CandidateTransactionRepository candidateTransactionRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TransactionTypeRepository transactionTypeRepository;

    @Override
    public void saveTransactionProgress(String candidateId,CandidateProgressRequestBO candidateProgressRequestBO) throws ONBException {

        CandidateTransaction savedInstance = new CandidateTransaction();

        TransactionType transactionType ;

        CandidateTransaction candidate;
        if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(candidateProgressRequestBO.getStepStatus()))
            throw new ONBException("No Transaaction to Save! Transaction Object Empty",new Exception());
        else {
            for(CandidateProgressBO candidateProgress : candidateProgressRequestBO.getStepStatus()) {
                transactionType = new TransactionType();

                candidate = new CandidateTransaction();
                candidate.setCandidateId(candidateId);

                transactionType.setTransTypeName(candidateProgress.getStep().name());

                candidate.setTransactionType(transactionType);
                candidate.setMODIFIED_DATE(new Date());
                savedInstance = candidateTransactionRepository.save(candidate);

                System.out.println("Saved Isntance "+savedInstance);
            }
        }   

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the right thing to do if you want to reference an existing entity is to fetch it from the `EntityManager` or since you are using Spring Data JPA from the repository.

For getting the instance you want to use [`JpaRepository.getOne`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-) which uses [`EntityManager.getReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-) and thereby not access the database.

Note that also the mapping you have in the code does not seem to match the description. It seems the relation `transactionType` should be marked as `ManyToOne`.

Comment: Thanks, Was unsure about the mapping, will update it to manytoOne.

Comment: Also, would that be a good approach if I cache the master data into second level cache and use it whenever required??

Comment: I think using a cache is not necessary. See my update of the answer. I'm not sure if this avoids a select during the persisting, but then I'm also not sure if using the 2nd level cache would. Just give it a try and maybe document your observation here.

Comment: Going for first approach where in we opted to hit a separate query to fetch PK from transaction_type table, second level cache requires some research, so as soon as we will get time we surely will try that and update the outcome here,